# Quotient of two integrals $\frac{\int_0^\pi x^3\ln(\sin x)\,dx}{\int_0^\pi x^2\ln(\sqrt{2}(\sin x))\,dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate
>   $$\frac{\int_0^\pi x^3\ln(\sin x)\,dx}{\int_0^\pi x^2\ln(\sqrt{2}(\sin x))\,dx}$$

In this problem, I'm unable to understand how to start.

I tried applying integration by parts but I couldn't solve it. I also tried the various properties of definite integration but they were of no use.
Maybe applying integration by parts (or DI method) successively may work but it leads to a form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: How in the denominator do you handle the logarithm's argument changing sign at $\pi/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: Where did you get this integral? Is it a part of some larger problem?

Comment: No , It is from a hard book for JEE Advanced that my coaching school has given me. It is a standalone question , I have been asked that this equates to kπ , and we have to find the value of k , The answer provided is 1.5 , but no solution has been given.

Comment: I *highly* doubt that either integral can be computed in closed form without knowledge of the Riemann zeta function *at least*. Perhaps you miscoppied the question, and wrote $$\ln(\sin(x\sqrt{2}))$$ instead of $$\ln(\sqrt{2}\sin x)$$ . I am not even sure if the integral on the denominator even exists. It would also help if you added more context to your question.

Comment: @Threesidedcoin I am so so so so so sorry. I'll make sure this doesn't happen in the future

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We want to prove that: $$\frac{I}{J}=\frac{\int_0^\pi x^3\ln(\sin x)dx} {\int_0^\pi x^2\ln\left(\sqrt 2\sin x\right)dx}=\frac{3\pi}2$$

First, let's take the $I$ integral and perform the $x\to \pi-x$ substitution:

$$I=\int_0^\pi x^3\ln(\sin x)dx\overset{x\to\pi-x}=\int_0^\pi (\pi^3-3\pi^2x+3\pi x^2-x^3)\ln(\sin x)dx$$

In the $J$ integral we had an additional $\ln \sqrt 2$ for the $x^2$ term, thus we can also add it here:

$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^\pi (\pi^3-3\pi^2x+3\pi x^2-x^3)\ln(\sin x)dx+ 3\pi(\underbrace{\ln \sqrt 2-\ln \sqrt 2}_{=0})\int_0^\pi x^2 dx$$

$$=\pi^3 \underbrace{\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)dx}_{=\mathcal L}-3\pi^2 \underbrace{\int_0^\pi x\ln(\sin x)dx}_{=\mathcal K}+3\pi J-I-{\pi^4}\ln \sqrt 2$$

$$\Rightarrow 2I=\left(\pi^3-\frac{3\pi^3}{2}\right)\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)dx+3\pi J-{\pi^4}\ln \sqrt 2$$

$$\require{cancel} 2I=\cancel{\frac{\pi^3}{2}\cdot 2\pi \ln \sqrt 2}+3\pi J-\cancel{\pi^4 \ln \sqrt 2}\Rightarrow I=\frac{3\pi}2J$$

---

Note that above we used:
$$\mathcal K=\int_0^\pi x\ln(\sin x)dx\overset{x\to \pi-x}=\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)\ln(\sin x)dx$$

$$\Rightarrow  \mathcal K=\frac{\pi}{2}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)dx}_{=\mathcal L}=\frac{\pi}{2}\mathcal L$$

$$\mathcal L=\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\sin x)dx+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\cos x)dx$$

$$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln\left(\sin x\cos x\right)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\sin 2x)dx-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2dx$$

$$=\frac12 \underbrace{\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x) dx}_{=\mathcal L}-\ln\sqrt 2 \int_0^{\pi} dx\Rightarrow \mathcal L=-2\pi \ln\sqrt 2$$

Comment: Hi. How did you write $L=\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\sin x)dx+\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(\cos x)dx$?

Comment: @aarbee Split the LHS integral as a sum of two integrals with the bounds $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$ respectively. Then for the second integral, with the bounds $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$, let $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ and arrive at the integral with $\cos x$ in it.

Comment: Ohkay, thanks, got it.

Answer (score 4):

For those interest in the overkill approach, I will be providing closed forms for each integral with the use of special functions just for the hell of it.

---

We define
$$p=\int_0^\pi x^3\ln\sin x\,dx$$
We recall the definition of the [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) of order $2$:
$$\mathrm{Cl}_2(x)=-\int_0^x \ln\left|2\sin\frac{t}2\right|\,dt=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin kx}{k^2}$$
so
$$-\ln\left(2\sin \frac{x}2\right)=\mathrm{Cl}_1(x)=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\cos kx}{k}$$
and thus $$\ln\sin x=-\ln2-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\cos2kx}{k}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
p&=-\int_0^\pi x^3\left(\ln2+\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\cos2kx}{k}\right)dx\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}4\ln2-\frac1{16}\sum_{k\geq1}\frac1{k^5}\int_0^{2k\pi}x^3\cos x\,dx
\end{align}$$
We can use IBP to show that
$$\int_0^{2k\pi}x^3\cos x\,dx=12\pi^2k^2$$
Which I leave to you as a challenge.

Long story short,
$$p=-\frac{\pi^4}{4}\ln2-\frac{3\pi^2}4\zeta(3)$$
Where $\zeta(3)=\sum_{k\geq1}k^{-3}$ is [Apery's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant). And $\zeta(s)=\sum_{k\geq1}k^{-s}$ is the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

---

Next up:
$$q=\int_0^\pi x^2\ln(\sqrt{2}\sin x)\,dx=\frac{\pi^3}{6}\ln2+\int_0^\pi x^2\ln\sin x\,dx$$
Using the same series as last time,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi x^2\ln\sin x\,dx&=-\frac{\pi^3}{3}\ln2-\frac18\sum_{k\geq1}\frac1{k^4}\int_0^{2k\pi}x^2\cos x\,dx
\end{align}$$
IBP shows that $$\int_0^{2k\pi}x^2\cos x\,dx=4\pi k$$
So of course
$$\int_0^\pi x^2\ln\sin x\,dx=-\frac{\pi^3}{3}\ln2-\frac\pi2\zeta(3)$$
Hence
$$q=-\frac{\pi^3}{6}\ln2-\frac\pi2\zeta(3)$$

---

So the ratio in question is 
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{\frac{\pi^4}{4}\ln2+\frac{3\pi^2}4\zeta(3)}{\frac{\pi^3}{6}\ln2+\frac\pi2\zeta(3)}=\frac32\pi$$